# Compilation error with assignment expression

Tags: java, variable-assignment

How do I switch every two items in an array list?

For example:
"hi", "how", "are", "you" becomes:

"how", "hi", "you", "are"

This is my error (in practice-it):

> The compiler found a data type it was not expecting here. Sometimes this error occurs when you mistake = for == when comparing values
>
> unexpected type
> required: variable
> found   : value
> list.get(i) = list.get(i+1);
>
> unexpected type
> required: variable
> found   : value
> list.get(i+1) = temp;

This is what I have:

```
    public void switchPairs(ArrayList<String> list){
        String temp = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<= list.size(); i+2){
            temp = list.get(i);
            list.get(i) = list.get(i+1);
            list.get(i+1) = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you think `list.get(i) = ...` should do? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use the return of the `get` method as a variable.  Unlike array access expressions, e.g. `arr[i] = value`, which are legal, the results of method calls cannot be used this way.  You must use the [`set` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set-int-E-) instead.

```
temp = list.get(i);
list.set(i, list.get(i + 1));
list.set(i + 1, temp);
```

This will fix the compiler error, but running this will guarantee an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

If the list size is even, then `list.get(i)` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when `i` reaches `list.size()`.  Remember that valid indexes are from `0` through `size() - 1`.

If the list size is odd, then `list.get(i + 1)` will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You must alter your `for` loop condition to stop before `i` *and* `i + 1` go out of bounds.  (The increment needs `+=` to have an effect here.)

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i+=2){
```

That will leave the last item in a list of odd size untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Because every method return a `value`, not a `variable`.

and the left operand of an assignment operator **must** be a variable, or a compile-time error occurs.

You can think like this way:
If the we can modify a variable via it's getter, that **encapsulation** makes nonsense, Since usually there is a getter for a private attribute.

In a word, in this case(and many other cases), you should use a setter to achieve your gold. Like this:

```
list.set(i, "something you want");
```